# How to add Sig Field to jsPDF for digital signature

Tags: jspdf

I would like to use node-signpdf to digitally sign a pdf document,

Their [example](https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf/blob/master/src/helpers.js#L12) uses pdfkit library and shows how to add a (digital) signature placeholder using the ref function to create PDF reference where pdf if pdfkit

```
export const addSignaturePlaceholder = ({pdf, reason, signatureLength = 8192}) => {
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle,no-param-reassign */
// Generate the signature placeholder
const signature = pdf.ref({
    Type: 'Sig',
    Filter: 'Adobe.PPKLite',
    SubFilter: 'adbe.pkcs7.detached',
    ByteRange: [
        0,
        DEFAULT_BYTE_RANGE_PLACEHOLDER,
        DEFAULT_BYTE_RANGE_PLACEHOLDER,
        DEFAULT_BYTE_RANGE_PLACEHOLDER,
    ],
    Contents: Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode(0).repeat(signatureLength)),
    Reason: new String(reason), // eslint-disable-line no-new-wrappers
    M: new Date(),
});
```

Using the placeholder to store the actual hash signature of the pdf as a buffer.

What I am missing is the way to do it using jsPDF.

Any idea or code snippet will be appreciated.